# Android VKontake official client. How to get authorized

Tags: android, android-intent, vk

I have on my device official App from VKontakte.

And I authorized there.

I try write own app which use VKontake API, but I need authorize.

Does there exist any way to get authorized status of user from official application with sending Intent with some action?

Comment: Hello Dmitry, Your problem is solved or not?

Comment: No it's not. Theny dont give Intents requests_codes - it can be solution, but they not exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now is it possible!
Please look through this tutorial
http://vk.com/dev/android_sdk

Also you can authorize via webview
Authorization in Vkontakte is an OAuth authorization. So following steps are similar for all services which use OAuth: Facebook, Instagram and etc.

1. Create application on vk.com:
   http://vk.com/editapp?act=create
2. Get it's ID.
3. In your login Activity open a webview with login url
   https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=APP_ID&scope=SETTINGS&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&display=DISPLAY&response_type=token

APP_ID is ID of your application. You will find it in VK -> Applications -> Settings -> Applications I manage (at the bottom) -> Manage

This login url will show a standard VK authorization dialog. There user will enter his login and password.

After that the user will be redirected to your Redirect-Uri. So you need to prepare a Redirect_Uri - that's a page which will be opened after successful login.

To that url will be concatenated an access_token. Access_token is the only parameter you need to store after the authorization. In next requests you'll just need to provide the access_token.

About other parameters you can read in VK site:
http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-17680044&p=Authorizing_Client_Applications

Comment: @robert How to upload photos to VKontake from my android application.